# Sending emails using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

class code:-

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Imports System.Net.Mail

Public Class SendEmail

    Private _Mailto As String = ""
    Public Property Mailto() As String
        Get
            Return _Mailto
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Mailto = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _MailSub As String = ""
    Public Property MailSub As String
        Get
            Return _MailSub
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _MailSub = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _MailBody As String = ""
    Public Property MailBody As String
        Get
            Return _MailBody
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _MailBody = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _Msg As String = ""
    Public ReadOnly Property Msg As String
        Get
            Return _Msg
        End Get
    End Property


    Public Sub email()
        Try
            Dim mail As New MailMessage()
            Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
            mail.From = New MailAddress("email@gmail.com")
            mail.[To].Add(_Mailto)
            mail.Subject = _MailSub
            mail.Body = _MailBody
            ' mail.Headers.Add("In-Reply-To", 1)
            SmtpServer.Port = 587
            SmtpServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@gamil.com", "password")

            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
            SmtpServer.Send(mail)

            _Msg = " Check Your Mail "
        Catch ex As Exception
            _Msg = ex.Message
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

code inside the ctrl "button sub"

```
Dim objemail As New SendEmail
objemail.Mailto = txtEmail.Text
objemail.email()
LabelEmail.Text = "The email has been sent"
```

The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address, and i have tried to intilize vaild email in "mailto" field and ive removed everything in proprities and fields and not solved yet,,, Help :D

any soultion??

Answer (score 0):

Do you validate `txtEmail.Text` for a valid email address when user enters a value ?
If not, please do it.

Do you get some exception in `email()` method ?

Comment: yes exception in email() method but can i put custom vaildator or i have to make function ?

Comment: Please post your exception details in the question, so that people will be able to help you quickly.

You can use a RegularExpressionValidator control to validate email addresses. Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator%28v=vs.90%29 and http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: If _Mailto <> "" Then
            Return Regex.IsMatch(_Mailto, "\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*")
        Else
            Return False
        End Ifive added this code

Comment: Does it solve your question ? If it was only related to email address validation and my post have helped you, please mark it as answer. Otherwise, post the next question for someone else to be able to help you.

Comment: ive used regularexpressionValidator and nothing happend same error , Format exception was caught (The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address).

Comment: Can you post the string you are trying to send email to, along with the complete stack trace ?